# Передача файла c помощью сокетов

Tags: файлы, java, сокет

Доброго времени суток. У меня проблема с передачей файла. c помощью сокетов в Java отправляю файл пакетами с чанками по 8192 байт упаковываю в класс.

```
public class FileChunk extends BorisPacket 
{
private byte [] chunkarray;

public FileChunk(byte [] chunkarray) 
{
    super(BorisPacket.FILECHUNK);
    this.chunkarray = chunkarray;
}

@Override
public byte[] toByteArray() 
{
    byte [] array = new byte[chunkarray.length + 5];
    array[0] = type;
    array[1] = (byte)(chunkarray.length >> 24);
    array[2] = (byte)(chunkarray.length >> 16);
    array[3] = (byte)(chunkarray.length >> 8);
    array[4] = (byte)(chunkarray.length);
    for(int i=0; i<chunkarray.length; i++)
    {
        array[i+5] = chunkarray[i];
    }

    return array;
}

public byte[] getChunkarray() {
    return chunkarray;
}

}
```

Когда очередной чанк передан, сервер мявкает клиенту, что чанк принят успешно. После этого клиент может отправить другой чанк и т. д. В определенный момент сервер не может прочитать тип пакета.

Декодер пакета

```
package org.boris.server.handler;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.boris.server.core.ServerDecoder;
import org.boris.server.pack.BorisPacket;
import org.boris.server.pack.FileChunk;
import org.boris.server.pack.FilePacket;

public class BorisPacketDecoder implements ServerDecoder 
{

    @Override
    public Object decode(BufferedInputStream bin) throws IOException 
    {
        byte [] type = new byte[1];
        bin.read(type);

        BorisPacket pack = null;
        switch(type[0])
        {   
            case BorisPacket.SAVEFILE:
                byte [] filsisearr = new byte[12];
                bin.read(filsisearr);

                int length = filsisearr[3]&0xFF | (filsisearr[2]&0xFF) << 8 |
                            (filsisearr[1]&0xFF) << 16 | (filsisearr[0]&0xFF) << 24;

                long filesize = filsisearr[11]&0xFFL | (filsisearr[10]&0xFFL) << 8 |
                                (filsisearr[9]&0xFFL) << 16 | (filsisearr[8]&0xFFL) << 24 | 
                                (filsisearr[7]&0xFFL) << 32 | (filsisearr[6]&0xFFL) << 40 | 
                                (filsisearr[5]&0xFFL) << 48 | (filsisearr[4]&0xFFL) << 56;

                byte [] sarr = new byte[length];
                bin.read(sarr);
                String filename = new String(sarr);

                pack = new FilePacket(filesize, filename);
                break;

            case BorisPacket.FILECHUNK:
                byte [] chunkarr = new byte[4];
                bin.read(chunkarr);
                int chunksize = chunkarr[3]&0xFF | (chunkarr[2]&0xFF) << 8 |
                                (chunkarr[1]&0xFF) << 16 | (chunkarr[0]&0xFF) << 24;

                byte [] chunkarray = new byte[chunksize];
                bin.read(chunkarray);
                pack = new FileChunk(chunkarray);
                break;

            case BorisPacket.FILEEND:
                pack = new BorisPacket(BorisPacket.FILEEND);
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("errorpack");
                break;
        }
        return pack;

    }
}
```

Как видно, в первом байте потока хранится тип пакета. В определенный момент вообще левый. Я понял, что-то не догоняю в работе потоков. Написал вот такой костыль на клиенте, с ним все работает.

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(2);
    this.out.write(array,0, array.length);
    this.out.flush();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Update**
Чего же я не понимаю?
вот отравляю принимаю вот так на клиенте

```
public static class ClientThread extends Thread
{
    private ClientFrame frame;
    private Socket socket;
    private BufferedInputStream in;
    private BufferedOutputStream out;
    private BufferedInputStream filestream;
    private Long length;
    private int count, chunkindex;
    private PackDecoder decoder;
    public ClientThread(ClientFrame frame)
    {
        super();
        this.frame = frame;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try 
        {
            Config config = frame.getConfig();
            this.socket = new Socket(config.getServer(), config.getPort());
            this.in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            this.out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            this.out.flush();
            decoder = new PackDecoder();

            BorisPacket pack = null;
            byte [] filearr = null;

            while((pack = decoder.decode(in)) != null)
            {
                switch(pack.getType())
                {
                    case BorisPacket.CONNECT:
                        this.frame.write("Connected "+this.socket);
                        break;

                    case BorisPacket.READYACCEPT:
                        filearr =  new byte[config.getFilechunksize()];
                        this.getChunk(filearr);
                        this.send(new FileChunk(filearr));
                        break;

                    case BorisPacket.CHUNKOK:
                        if(chunkindex > count)
                            this.send(new BorisPacket(BorisPacket.FILEEND));
                        else
                        {
                            frame.progressBar.setValue(chunkindex);
                            this.getChunk(filearr);
                            this.send(new FileChunk(filearr));
                        }
                        break;

                }
            }
        } 
        catch (UnknownHostException e) 
        {
            frame.write("Неудалось поключиться удаленный хост не отвечает");
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            frame.write("Неудалось поключиться удаленный хост не отвечает");
            this.interrupt();
        }
    }

    public void send(byte [] array) throws IOException
    {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2);
            this.out.write(array);
            this.out.flush();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void send(BorisPacket pack) throws IOException
    {
        this.send(pack.toByteArray());
    }

    public void setFile(File file)
    {
        try 
        {
            //отправляем  размер файла  и чанка
            length = file.length();
            send(new FilePacket(length, file.getName()));
            filestream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            count = (int) (length/frame.getConfig().getFilechunksize());
            chunkindex = 0;
            frame.progressBar.setMaximum(count);
            frame.progressBar.setValue(0);
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e1) 
        {
            frame.write("Невозможно открыть файл");
        } 
        catch (IOException e2) 
        {
            frame.write("не удалось отправить файл");
            return;
        }
    }

    private void getChunk(byte [] filearr)
    {
        if(count == chunkindex)
        {
            int finalchunck = (int)(length % frame.getConfig().getFilechunksize());
            filearr = new byte[finalchunck];
        }

        try 
        {
            filestream.read(filearr);
            chunkindex ++;
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            frame.write("ошибка чтения файла");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ничего не понял: можно подробнее как вы отправляете - что-то не наблюдаю многопоточности

Comment: `send`, `setFile` и проч. объявите как `synchronized`

Comment: хорошо попробую

Comment: не работает. В работе буфферизованных потоков ввода вывода. вот в чем вопрос. почему после отправки очередного чанка при приеме в черти что. хотя должен быть нормальный пакет.

Comment: я кидаю файл чанками по 8 килобайт добавляя еще заголовок пакета 5 байт.  я уменьшил размер чанка до 1 килобайта и файлы стали передаваться без проблем.